# How to store queries inside a MongoDB collection in order to execute them dynamically?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm new at MongoDB. I have a "Report" dropdown in my interface and depending of the report selected a query is executed.

On the other hand I have a "reports" collection for example like this:

```
{
  _id : 1,
  reportName : "Count users",
  queryScript : "db.users.count()"
}, {
  _id : 2,
  reportName : "Find user names",
  queryScript : "db.users.find( {}, { name : true } )"
}, etc
```

We have to do something similar to this pseudo code:

```
Report report = db.reports.find({ id : 1 });
String result = mongoClient.execute ( report.getQueryScript );
```

Is it possible? Can you give a hand on this?

Comment: do be aware that THIS IS NOT A STORED PROCEDURE also there is not much point to doing what your dong, there is no performance beenfit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [server side javascript](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/):

```
db.system.js.save({
     _id : "countUsers" ,
     value : function (){ return db.test.count(); }
});
```

and so on. But keep the _id as a normal name of the function, because you will later evoke it by _id. Then you do

```
db.loadServerScripts();
```

and after this you can execute your query:

```
countUsers();
```

Comment: Why do you customers have access to your database? Why not to give them an interface through which they can access a list of predefined queries and to see the results? And no, you can not store java classes in mongo